# type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, dataframe, import, finance

I've just started a python for finance course and am brand new to programming. I'm trying to import a csv file into "fb" dataframe but it keeps giving me the following error: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_csv'.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
fb=pd.DataFrame.read_csv('data/facebook.csv')
```

Comment: `fb=pd.read_csv('data/facebook.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
fb=pd.DataFrame.read_csv('data/facebook.csv')
```

Try

```
fb=pd.read_csv('data/facebook.csv')
```

Comment: Tried that, it worked but its giving me a permission error now:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Ayush\\Downloads'

I'm on my admin account so I don't know what the problem is